# Oracle VM - lubuntu 16.10 - guest additions not working

Tags: mount, virtualbox, lubuntu, guest-additions

I know its a common issue, but I couldn't find a solution online.

I downloaded the ISO (32 bit) from here: http://lubuntu.net/blog/lubuntu-1610-yakkety-yak-released

I mounted the guest additional from input -> insert guest additions CD image.

Then I started `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`.

I enabled shared clipboard and drag and drop, neither work Nor does the shared folder I tried to mount.

I figure the problem is something with the guest additions - but every time I try to install again, it says that its updated.

When I try running `modprobe vboxsf` , as I have seen suggested,  I get `ERROR: could not insert 'vboxsf': Operation not permitted`.

Also used `sudo gpasswd -a username vboxsf` to add myself to the user group, it said it worked but then again, the above operations still aren't working.

`modinfo vboxsf` output:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-22-generic/misc/vboxsf.ko
version:        5.1.18 r114002
alias:          fs-vboxsf
license:        GPL
author:         Oracle Corporation
description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox VFS Module for Host File System Access
srcversion:     B90FAA646E076EF187EC29B
depends:        vboxguest
vermagic:       4.8.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
parm:           follow_symlinks:Let host resolve symlinks rather than showing them (int)
```

`dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii` output :

```
bar@bar-VirtualBox:~$ dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii
ii  virtualbox                     5.1.6-dfsg-2 i386         x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
ii  virtualbox-dkms                5.1.6-dfsg-2 all          x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
ii  virtualbox-guest-additions-iso 5.1.6-1      all          guest additions iso image for VirtualBox
ii  virtualbox-guest-dkms          5.1.6-dfsg-2 all          x86 virtualization solution - guest addition module source for dkms
ii  virtualbox-guest-source        5.1.6-dfsg-2 all          x86 virtualization solution - guest addition module source
ii  virtualbox-guest-utils         5.1.6-dfsg-2 i386         x86 virtualization solution - non-X11 guest utilities
ii  virtualbox-guest-x11           5.1.6-dfsg-2 i386         x86 virtualization solution - X11 guest utilities
ii  virtualbox-qt                  5.1.6-dfsg-2 i386         x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
bar@bar-VirtualBox:~$
```

Comment: Can you post all the error messages?

Comment: Did you log out/in after putting username in group vboxsf? That'll fix your shared folder problem. Clipboard and drag/drop has always been a problem. Are you running VB 5.1.22?

Comment: @Arun For which commands? The only real 'error' I encountered is the modprobe one, but still, it doesn't work.

Comment: You mean modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found.?

Comment: @heynnema I restarted the VM, but I still don't have access to the shared folder in /media/shared_name, even tho auto-mount is on. I'm not sure how to check the VB version?

Comment: @Arun I mean :    ERROR: could not insert 'vboxsf': Operation not permitted. I did get a similar error earlier (with vboxsf not drv) but it changed to that error once I installed a few things

Comment: What is current error

Comment: @Arun ERROR: could not insert 'vboxsf': Operation not permitted.

Comment: Run `uname -a` and tell output

Comment: @Arun Linux bar-VirtualBox 4.8.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 8 09:14:42 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: now run `modinfo vboxsf` and tell output

Comment: @Arun I added it to the question because it was formatted without spaces as a comment

Comment: See my answer .

Comment: The shared folder will appear in your Files window, and it'll be called something like sf_foldername. If you're still not running, edit your question with `dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii`.

Comment: @heynnema I couldn't see it. Added the output of the command.

Comment: You have too many virtualbox things installed, and they're all older versions. You only need **virtualbox** and the current version is 5.1.22. Since this is a new VB install, I'd recommend uninstalling all of your VB software, getting the latest 5.1.22, installing it, and start over. I suspect you'll be fine then. Also, in your guest OS, type `groups bar` and confirm that you're in the vboxsf group. Report back.

Comment: Extremely weird, but it seems to be working now - the folder suddenly appeared on my desktop after I rebooted. For future reference,  I updated with System tools -> Software Updater, pretty sure it would work from the terminal too.